# SwiftUI Picker inside Menu does not initially show checkmark for selected option

Tags: swift, swiftui, menu

I am trying to implement a `Picker` embedded inside a `Menu` in SwiftUI, following this [post](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/08/05/menus-in-swiftui/). However, there seems to be a bug where the picker does not initially show a checkmark next to the currently selected option when embedded inside a Menu.

```
Menu {
    Picker("Unit", selection: $food.servingSize.unit) {
        ForEach(units) { unit in
            Text(unit.name).tag(unit)
        }
    }
} label: {
    Text(food.servingSize.unit.shorthand)
}
```

[image]

However, if I don't use `Menu` and just the `Picker` by itself instead, the default selection works as expected:

```
Picker("Unit", selection: $food.servingSize.unit) {
    ForEach(units) { unit in
        Text(unit.name).tag(unit)
    }
}
.pickerStyle(.menu)
```

[image]

Obviously I want to use the `Menu` in order to change what is being displayed after selection from the Picker. What am I missing here?

Comment: Works fine here. It seems it is in some other code, maybe type mismatching. Would you prepare minimal reproducible example so we analyse how do you do it?